# List of false friends

Tags: vocabulary

Is there a short list of the most common false friends for translating Latin into English?

Comment: I know my old Latin Prose Composition book had a list of the most commonly confused ones (*vilis*, *mortalis*, etc). I'll see if I can find it tomorrow.

Comment: @Draconis - wait, how is *mortalis* a false friend...?

Comment: There is a *Vicipaedia* article on this subject: https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsus_amicus

Comment: @brianpck When it's used as a synonym of "lethal" (e.g. a mortal wound). I should have specified that.

Comment: @Luc I think Latin Vicipaedia has a real credibility issue: a lot of these articles read like high-school research projects. Even the title "Falsus Amicus" rings bad in my ears.

Comment: “*Falsus amicus*” isn’t very imaginative indeed, but there are some false friends examples in the article.

Comment: Even the English Wikipedia page on false friends is terrible. It seems some people do not like the idea of separating false friends from false cognates.